# Laravel: Displaying the error message of an input array specific index

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Input array and i want to output the error of each specific index so if my `$input[0]` and `$input[1]` meets an error they should be display while the other input lets say `$input[2]` didn't meet error then it shouldn't be display:

The `mmad_bonus_type` may confuse you because i'm using email for it. i'm just using the email validation rule for testing.

```
$length = $input['length'];

$rules = array();

for($i = 0, $c = $length; $i < $c; $i++){
  $rules['mmad_bonus_type'][$i] = 'email';
}

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $message);

if($validator->fails()){
    return Response::json($validator->messages());
}
print_r($rules);
```

Heres the output of my `print_r` :

```
 [mmad_bonus_type] => Array
    (
        [0] => email
        [1] => email
        [2] => email
        [3] => email
    )
```

If i ran the code only single error outputted for the `mmad_bonus_type` input.

Here is the var_dump of my inputs:

```
 array(11) {
  ["length"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["mtype"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["startfrom"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["endfrom"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["mmad_bonus_type"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["mmad_total_wins"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["mmad_starting_date"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["mmad_starting_time"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["mmad_ending_date"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["mmad_ending_time"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "ry0o35m0pP6xBF5N9YoXEUtMzGn50U36caJ4W37E"
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a `var_dump($input);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator uses array_dot notation for the array keys. For example, if you had an input like `<input type="text" name="user[name]" />`, your validation rule would have the key 'user.name'.

The same format goes for numeric indexes, as well. So, if, for example, you had:

```
<input type="text" name="mmad_bonus_type[]" />
<input type="text" name="mmad_bonus_type[]" />
<input type="text" name="mmad_bonus_type[]" />
```

Then your validation rules would be:

```
$rules = array(
    'mmad_bonus_type.0' => 'email',
    'mmad_bonus_type.1' => 'email',
    'mmad_bonus_type.2' => 'email',
);
```

In your case, I'm assuming you have an array of `mmad_bonus_type` inputs with numeric indexes, so you're probably looking for something like:

```
for($i = 0, $c = $length; $i < $c; $i++){
    $rules['mmad_bonus_type.'.$i] = 'email';
}
```

Comment: i also tried that before but it doest work if im going to print_r the rule here is the output 

    [mmad_bonus_type.0] => email
    [mmad_bonus_type.1] => email

Comment: I add the name of my input through jquery by the way. so instead of mmaed_bonus_type[] in ur example the mmad_bonus_type[0] has a default value with me which is the index start from 0 until the length of input.

Comment: @frustratedprogrammer If the value of `mmad_bonus_type[0]` is empty (as shown in your var_dump), then the simple validation rule of 'email' will pass (if the value is not required, then the empty string is valid). As a test to get you on your way, change the validation rule to 'required|email'.

Comment: i tried adding a required rule but theres an error. here is the error. 

{"error":{"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Method [validateEmail|required] does not exist.","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tangkas_admin_\\tangkas_admin_\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator.php","line":2572}}

Comment: here's a clear preview ----- message: "Method [validateEmail|required] does not exist."

Comment: @frustratedprogrammer You have to change the rule keys to the format I have specified in my answer. If you leave them like you had them, you'll get that error message.